# How do I show all WPF tagged questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-watching

On stackoverflow.com, when I add "WPF" as an interesting tag, and then click it, it briefly shows the questions and then the page goes blank.

Note that this does not happen when clicking any of the other tags that I've flagged as interesting. In other words, clicking something like SQL correctly shows all of the questions tagged as SQL.

Thanks

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf work properly? Do you by any chance have WPF as an ignored tag also?

Comment: mmyers is on to something. I set a tag to be both "interesting" and "ignored" (not unlike me) and saw the behavior that Mssr. Kane describes. (@mmyers you should make that an answer.)

Comment: @Al Everett: I wonder why I didn't get a notification even though you wrote "@mmyers"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have also ignored the wpf tag and checked the "Hide ignored tags" box in your profile, then this would cause the problem you are seeing.

Comment: yes, this is the answer